Strict validation for Angular material datepicker
currently I'm using Angular material datepicker and I allow user to select date from calendar or directly input in field manually.
Currently if user input "5-5-5" and click outside it will automatically converts date to "05/05/2005" but I want strict validation if user enter any format except dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy it should show my validations instead of converting it automatically
I tried finding a way in documentation but not much details found related to it

This is fairly well documented in the "Setting the selected date" part of the documentation, which links to another section "Choosing a date implementation and date format settings". Read the whole page very thoroughly to fully understand the concepts of date adapters.
It clearly states that:

provideNativeDateAdapter is based off the functionality available in
JavaScript's native Date object. Thus it is not suitable for many
locales. One of the biggest shortcomings of the native Date object is
the inability to set the parse format. We strongly recommend using an
adapter based on a more robust formatting and parsing library. You can
use provideMomentDateAdapter or a custom DateAdapter that works with
the library of your choice.

So, if you're using that, you won't be able to enforce proper parsing. If you switch to some other provider, it might be possible to use stricter parsing. If none of the adapters suits your needs, you are free to write a custome adapter with your custom logic, including parsing.
As an example, MomentDateAdapter has an option to pass strict: true, which will enforce strict parsing of the passed values based on the provided MatDateFormats config. Other adapters might have different settings.
I've forked the sample from the docs which enforces the DD-MM-YYYY format here.
Note two parts in particular:
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

which defines how the dates will be displayed and what is the expected input.
And:
 providers: [
    // Moment can be provided globally to your app by adding `provideMomentDateAdapter`
    // to your app config. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations
    // of our example generation script.
    provideMomentDateAdapter(MY_FORMATS, { strict: true }),
  ],

which says to use the formats defined above, and use strict parsing methods.
